# Projectile motion prolem

Tags: math-software

The graph of the equation 
$$h= -at^2 + bt + c$$ 
which describes how the height, $h$ of a hit basketball changes over time which is $t$ is shown in the figure that is below

[image]

If You alter only the $c$ term in the given equation, which gives the height at time $t = 0$, what effect the alteration has with the calculations?

Comment: "Please Someone Give This Question A Good Title And Tag(s)"... that's actually the job of the person asking the question.

Comment: u don't know because u have reputation but i don't!!!

Comment: See [Projectile motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion): "This curved path was shown by Galileo to be a parabola. "

Comment: That is why we say:
"Look before you think
Think before you speak!"

Comment: With $t=0$ you have $h=c$. This means that the ball is cicked not at ground level but at height $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quadratic in the form of $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ will have $c$ as its $y$-intercept, since $f(0)=a(0)^2+b(0)+c$, and thus, $f(0)=c$.

Due to this, altering the $c$ term will change the quadratic's $y$-intercept.

The $y$ value at time $t=0$ represents the initial height of the ball.

Therefore, in your example, changing the $c$ value of the quadratic will change the initial height, or the height of the ball after $0$ seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it somehow answered my question. Thanks

Comment: Please mark it correct by clicking the check mark.

Comment: ok if u wish i like u

Comment: want it? Ill Give it to u!!!

Comment: Done man good work